# protobuf_generate grpc_cpp_plugin fails with status code 1

Tags: c++, cmake, grpc, conan, protoc

I'm trying to generate grpc cpp files but the generator plugin fails when I call it in cmake

```
find_package(protoc CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(gRPC CONFIG REQUIRED)
get_target_property(grpc_cpp_plugin_location gRPC::grpc_cpp_plugin LOCATION) #get plugin location
get_target_property(protoc_location protobuf::protoc LOCATION) #for sanity check
message("protoc is at ${protoc_location}") #for sanity check
message("grpc plugin is at ${grpc_cpp_plugin_location}") #for sanity check
add_library(${PRO_NAME} ${PRO_SRCS} test.proto)

protobuf_generate(TARGET ${PRO_NAME} LANGUAGE cpp)
protobuf_generate(TARGET ${PRO_NAME} LANGUAGE grpc GENERATE_EXTENSIONS .grpc.pb.h .grpc.pb.cc PLUGIN "protoc-gen-grpc=${grpc_cpp_plugin_location}")
```

Produces an error like

```
protoc is at /home/user/.conan/data/protoc_installer/...
grpc plugin is at /home/user/.conan/data/grpc/...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: 
[ 16%] Running grpc protocol buffer compiler on test.proto
protoc-gen-grpc: program not found or is not executable
Please specify a program using absolute path or make sure the program is available in your PATH system variable
--grpc_out: protoc-gen-grpc: Plugin failed with status code 1
```

but if I use it manually in a shell script it works even though i copy the file path from the cmake output

```
PROTOC=${PATH FROM CMAKE}
GRPCC=${PATH FROM CMAKE}
$PROTOC -I src/ --grpc_out=. --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=$GRPCC test.proto
```

basing method off of https://www.falkoaxmann.de/dev/2020/11/08/grpc-plugin-cmake-support.html

I initially thought my issue was a library path error, I'm using a remote build server with conan import management, but I verified that the plugins rpath includes the relative locations of the libraries it needs.

Comment: Is `protoc-gen-grpc` in a folder in your `$PATH`?

Comment: @PaulSanders no, its in a folder downloaded by a package manager so i can't trust it to be in any specific place. To run it in cli I used the full path to it but i copied it from the path cmake was finding it at.

Comment: You could try putting a copy of that file in a folder in your path - in `/usr/local/bin`, say.

Comment: You might be running into the same issue as https://github.com/faaxm/exmpl-cmake-grpc/issues/1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is probably that cmake uses an outdated protobuf config, or rather the `FindProtobuf.cmake` that comes with cmake rather than `ProtobufConfig.cmake` that comes with the protobuf package.

To fix this, compile gRPC yourself and use the `-DgRPC_PROTOBUF_PACKAGE_TYPE=CONFIG` flag when you run cmake for gRPC.

The problem comes from gRPC having its own `find_package(Protobuf)` call in its gRPCConfig.cmake which, depending on the `gRPC_PROTOBUF_PACKAGE_TYPE`, might run in MODULE mode. (and in module mode, it will find the legacy FindProtobuf.cmake)

Have a look at the recently added github workflow for an example on how to build dependencies and the example:
https://github.com/faaxm/exmpl-cmake-grpc/blob/master/.github/workflows/build.yml